# Some site seems not share the stackoverflow cookies, I have to login one by one

Tags: support, login, auto-login

It is weird only happen on chrome at home.

At company, it does share the login session/cookies.

After I login `stackoverflow`,  only `stackexchange.com` can recognize the cookies. But `askubuntu` , `superuser`, `serverfault` don't let me auto login.

What's wrong?

Comment: Useless anecdotal comment.. this definitely happened to me before and doesn't happen any more. No idea why.

Comment: That's because they're all on their own domains, you need to allow cookies from those domains as well.